# getting permission to execute a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

im trying to get my server to execute a simple bash script:

```
   #!/bin/bash          
   echo Hello World
```

After saving this to /var/www/script (im saving it to the web directory for no reason in particular) i try and execute it with

```
exec /var/www/script
```

This fails returning i don't have permission to execute it, `sudo exec` isn't a thing so i do `sudo -i` then run `exec /var/www/script` as root and i still have permission denied. I fairly uncertain why executing it as root doesn't work. Im wondering if i'm

A) using the wrong command to execute a bash script
B) have incorrect formatting in the script
C) shouldn't have saved it to /var/www/
D) done some other thing that i'm not even aware of.

Im running ubuntu server 16.04 if that helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### File Permissions

First, make sure that you have the correct file permissions:

```
chmod +x /var/www/script_name #Gives the current user execute permissions
```

### Executing Your Bash Script

In order to execute your `bash` script, the easiest option is to just simply call it (without any additional commands) by typing in the relative path to the script:

```
/var/www/script_name
```

There are other options for explicitly executing your script from the shell (in your case, use the `bash` shell to execute your script as a `bash` script). From [TLDP documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html)...

> A script can also explicitly be executed by a given shell, but generally we only do this if we want to obtain special behavior, such as checking if the script works with another shell or printing traces for debugging:

```
rbash script_name.sh # Execute using the restricted bash shell
sh script_name.sh # Execute using the sh shell
bash -x script_name.sh # Execute using the bash shell
```

### A Note on File Extensions: "Shebang" line > File extension

It is not an advised practice to use file extensions with your scripts, especially if you think your code may evolve beyond its current functionality.

Just in case you were wondering if the file extension may be your problem... it is not. It is important that you know that the file extension of a script isn't necessary at all. What matter is what you put in the "shebang" line:

To use the `sh` shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

To use the `bash` shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It won't matter what file extension you use - the "shebang" line indicates what shell will be used to execute the script. You could save a script with the "shebang" of `#!/bin/bash` as `script_name.py`, but it would remain a `bash` script. If you attempt to execute it, `./script_name.py`, it would be executed as a `bash` script.

As @Arjan mentioned in the comments, using file extensions for your script could lead to unnecessary complications if you decide to change the implementation of your project (i.e., a different shell / language):

> I could decide later to shift my project to `sh`, `python`, `perl`, `C`, etc. Perhaps because I want to add functionality. Perhaps because I want to make it portable to a system without `bash`. It would be much more difficult if I used the `.sh` file extension, since then I'd need to change all my references to the script just because I changed its implementation.

Comment: Why does one need to make sure to save a `bash` script as `script_name.sh` ?  Are you sure that any `bash` script will run in `sh` and `sh script_name.sh` will always work for `bash` scripts?

Comment: It's not Ubuntu's bash scripting documentation and there's nothing official about it.  It's a **user-created** community wiki page.  It says, *(typically the .sh file extension is used for your reference, but is not necessary. In our examples, we will be using the .sh extension).*  I think it's purely for this context of the beginners guide.  None of the scripts in Ubuntu's `/etc/init.d/` directory carry that extension, for example.  I'd argue *against* using the .sh extension, it's an implementation detail.  What if my script is used in hundred places and I change it to a python script?

Comment: For the other question, can you try this:  save `var="blah" ; cat <<< $var` in a file, and run it with `bash <script_name>` and `sh <script_name>`?
`bash` is not `sh`.  Bash has extensions and running bash scripts in sh can fail horribly.

Comment: @Arjan Oh, that make sense - I'll edit my answer to reflect the `bash` and `sh` difference, that's a key I didn't think to account for. But, wouldn't it still be preferred to use the `.bash` extension instead of none at all? What benefit does using **no** file extension have when naming a script?

Comment: Well I don't know why you would change it to a python script.  Not knowing is the point, actually, while python was just an example.  I could decide later to use sh, python, perl, write a C program...  Perhaps because I want to add functionality.  Perhaps because I must make it portable to a system without `bash`.  It'd be nasty if I'd need to change all my references to the script just because I changed its implementation.  Or if I must then use a C program with the sh extension.  Or clutter my bin dir with symlinks.

Comment: @Arjan Ok! That makes sense. In fact, I really like the explanation you provided. Do you mind if I include wording from this explanation within my answer (I'll cite you as the author)? I think it would be useful, just in case the OP isn't clear on the use of file extensions (as I was, until you explained it just now).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, any user content on SO is licensed under [cc by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), so sure :)

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices:

1. Run it as an argument to bash:

   ```
   bash /var/www/script
   ```
2. Alternatively, set the execute bit:

   ```
   chmod +x /var/www/script
   ```

   And, now you can execute it directly:

   ```
   /var/www/script
   ```